# I want to use webbrowser-app in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, webbrowser-app

I love this browser, it is very quick, even in heavy sites. I would like to upload files with that.. I can't upload pictures for example to facebook, it is a disable option?, or what I can do about?.. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that is not possible with the standard Ubuntu web-browser. The reason for this is that it's not Javascript enabled.

If it is the minimalistic, simplicity and speed of it you like, you may want to try Epiphany web browser.

To install that open the Software Centre and search "Epiphany web" and hit enter. Install that and you will be able to add images to Facebook without any problem. :)

Any problems, just give me a shout I'll be on the couch doing what my username suggests!